# Program gets stuck with tornado

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tornado

I'm trying to make a Raspberry Pi send plain text to my phone over my local network, from where I plan to pick it up.

I tried the following "hello world"-like program from their official website, but I cannot get it to proceed after a point.

```py
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Ugh, the world? Well.. hello, I guess")


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

application.listen(8881)

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

# I cannot get this line to execute!!
print("Hi!!")
```

Experience: basics of Python, intermediate with Arduino C++, none in networking/web

Comment: According to documentation "The IOLoop.start method (or equivalently, asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_forever) should usually be called at the end of the main()" so code after it will never be executed.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Tornado uses an event loop. Any code after you start the server with `.start()` will not be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to print to STDOUT after starting the event loop, so that print statement never sees the light of the day. Basically, you're creating a HTTP server at port 8881 that is constantly listening for requests. Whatever logic you wish the server to do needs to be in a callback, like `MainHandler`

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Ugh, the world? Well.. hello, I guess")
        # All your SMS logic potentially goes here
        self.write("Sent SMS to xyz...")


application = tornado.web.Application(
    [
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ]
)

application.listen(8881)

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Then trigger the endpoint by making an HTTP call

```
curl <IP ADDRESS OF YOUR PI>:8881
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Tornado's `IOLoop.start()` method is a "blocking" call, which means that it doesn't return until some condition is met. This is why your code "gets stuck" on that line. The [documentation for this method](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.start) states:

> Starts the I/O loop.
>
> The loop will run until one of the callbacks calls stop(), which will
> make the loop stop after the current event iteration completes.

Typically, a call to `IOLoop.start()` will be the last thing in your program. The exception would be if you want to stop your Tornado application and then proceed to do something else.

Here are two possible solutions to your problem, depending on what you want to accomplish:

1. call `self.stop()` from the handler. This will stop the Tornado application, `IOLoop.start()` will return, and then your print will execute.
2. call `print("Hi!!")` from your handler.